# Can't Get Images in Web to Paste into Word 2010

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, copy

I've read all the other posts about this on here and other forums, but nothing suggested in them helps.  Images were pasting into Word fine up to yesterday, and now only text pastes.  Other options I've ruled out: I am viewing Word document in "Print Layout view"; The Show drawings and text boxes on screen option is turned on.  The Print drawings created in Word option turned on.
The Use draft quality option is turned off.  I am using the In line with text option with the picture or with the object; however the Picture Placeholders option is turned off.

This also happens when I switch from trying to copy and paste images from Chrome browser to Firefox, so it does not appear to be a "browser specific" problem/issue.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Cfguy

Comment: I am not sure. Check Trust Center options. I just copied an image from Web and pasted it successfully into Word 2010 on Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: Just for a test, could you pate the image from the webpage opend via IE? I would suggest you reset IE browser.